# Why is Valgrind finding errors in this hash table test case?

Tags: c, memory, pthreads, valgrind

I took it upon myself to develop a concurrent generic hash table in C.

Relevant contents of `hash_table.h`:

```
typedef struct list_node {
    void * data;
    struct list_node * next;
} list_node_t;


typedef struct hash_table {
    int max_size;
    int count;
    list_node_t * * elements;
    pthread_rwlock_t * locks;
    pthread_rwlock_t global_table_lock;
    hash_table_compare_function compare;
    hash_table_hash_function hash;
} hash_table_t;
```

Relevant contents of `hash_table.c`:

```
#define LOCK_RD(lock)   pthread_rwlock_rdlock(&lock);
#define LOCK_WR(lock)   pthread_rwlock_wrlock(&lock);
#define UNLOCK(lock)    pthread_rwlock_unlock(&lock);

bool
hash_table_remove(hash_table_t * table, void * element)
{
    int hash_value = table->hash(element);
    list_node_t * node, * prev;

    LOCK_WR(table->locks[hash_value]);

    node = table->elements[hash_value];
    prev = NULL;

    while (node) {
        if (!table->compare(node->data, element)) {
            // value is first item in the list
            if (node == table->elements[hash_value]) {
                table->elements[hash_value] = node->next;
                free(node);
                UNLOCK(table->locks[hash_value]);
                LOCK_WR(table->global_table_lock);
                table->count--;
                UNLOCK(table->global_table_lock);
                return true;
            } else {
                // link previous node with one after current
                prev->next = node->next;
                free(node);
                UNLOCK(table->locks[hash_value]);
                LOCK_WR(table->global_table_lock);
                table->count--;
                UNLOCK(table->global_table_lock);
                return true;
            }
        }
        prev = node;
        node = node->next;
    }

    UNLOCK(table->locks[hash_value]);

    return false;
}
```

I wrote a test case which uses strings, in which this is the relevant code:

```
#include "hashtable.h"

#define NUM_THREADS 2
#define NUM_STRINGS 154560
#define NUM_LOOKUPS 10000


void *
do_work(void * data)
{
    int thread_id = *(int*)data;

    // write "threadX.txt" to filename, where X is the given thread id
    char filename[64];
    strcpy(filename, "thread");
    char thread_id_str[4];
    sprintf(thread_id_str, "%d", thread_id);
    strcat(filename, thread_id_str);
    strcat(filename, ".txt");

    FILE * file = fopen(filename, "r");
    char buffer[128];
    int i, num_str_per_thread = NUM_STRINGS / NUM_THREADS;
    char * str_array[num_str_per_thread];

    for (i = 0; i < num_str_per_thread; i++) {
        fgets(buffer, 128, file);

        str_array[i] = calloc((strlen(buffer) + 1), sizeof(char));
        strcpy(str_array[i], buffer);
    }

    fclose(file);

    for (i = 0; i < num_str_per_thread; i++)
        hash_table_insert(table, str_array[i]);

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_LOOKUPS; i++)
        hash_table_contains(table, str_array[rand() % num_str_per_thread]);

    for (i = 0; i < num_str_per_thread / 2; i++)
        hash_table_remove(table, str_array[rand() % num_str_per_thread]);

    //sleep(2); NOTE: no read errors reported if I leave this sleep() here.

    for (i = 0; i < num_str_per_thread; i++)
        if (str_array[i])
            free(str_array[i]);

    return NULL;
}


void
create_workers()
{
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
    int ids[NUM_THREADS];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
        ids[i] = i + 1;

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, do_work, (void*)&ids[i]);

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
}
```

The test case is supposed to work as follows: there are two files, thread1.txt and thread2.txt, each containing **unique** strings I have generated beforehand. I create two threads, and each will read from a file and store each string on an array of strings called `str_array`. They will then insert all these strings into the hash table and perform random searches (`hash_table_contains`) and deletions (`hash_table_remove`). Then, each will free their respective array of strings. However, when I run this test case, Valgrind reports the following:

[image]

[image]

Please note that there are no memory leaks. What I get from these errors is that a thread is, upon calling `hash_table_remove`, attempting to free memory already freed by `free(str_array[i])`. However, that makes no sense, since `hash_table_remove` is called before `free(str_array[i]`. I can't figure out what's giving me these invalid reads.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you shure that the data you read from file is '\0' terminated? That could corrupt your string buffer.

Comment: `strcpy` handles `\0` termination, if I am not mistaken. Thank you for the reply!

Comment: It's going to be hell working out what's going wrong without an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))
(or MRE or whatever name SO now uses;
MCVE was good for over five years and it did not need changing)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) to allow us to experiment.
Sufficiently hell-like that I'm not going to bother to attempt it until there is a _minimal_ example with (minimal) data that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @saucygote strcpy can't insert \0 if the source isn't terminated. It will continue copying until it reaches a \0 which may be past the end of the string buffer. But you will also have the same problem with strlen.

Comment: @jo-art: If `fgets()` succeeds, it always returns a string (which means it is null-terminated) - the source file doesn't need to have one.  However, the code in the question does not check if `fgets()` succeeded...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I took the time to make this question as understandable as possible, and there is no minimal set of data that reproduces the problem since it only occurs with rather large sets of data. How could I have improved the quality of this question?

Comment: How to improve?  Well, showing the main function would help.  If it just calls `create_workers()`, rename `create_workers()` to `main()`.  Then we'd know that there are no other untoward things happening in other code.  We shouldn't have to guess!  You have `strcpy(filename, "thread");
    char thread_id_str[4];
    sprintf(thread_id_str, "%d", thread_id);
    strcat(filename, thread_id_str);
    strcat(filename, ".txt");`  — that's a complicated way to write `snprintf(filename, sizeof(filename), "thread%d.txt", thread_id);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, your thread removes at most half the strings it inserted:

```
for (i = 0; i < num_str_per_thread / 2; i++)
    hash_table_remove(table, str_array[rand() % num_str_per_thread]);
```

(in fact, it is most likely to remove about 39% of the strings it inserted).

Then, it goes on to free *all* the strings it inserted:

```
for (i = 0; i < num_str_per_thread; i++)
    if (str_array[i])
        free(str_array[i]);
```

However, at least half (and most likely ~61%) of those strings are still in the hash table, where the other threads will try to compare them as they scan through the chained hash bucket entries.  That's your use-after-free error.

Instead of freeing all the strings, you could free them as you remove them:

```
for (i = 0; i < num_str_per_thread / 2; i++)
{
    int str_index = rand() % num_str_per_thread;

    if (str_array[str_index])
    {
        hash_table_remove(table, str_array[str_index]);
        free(str_array[str_index]);
        str_array[str_index] = NULL;
    }
}
```

At this point, the non-NULL entries in `str_array[]` are the strings still present in the hash table.  You can't free them until they're removed from the hash table (or the hash table is no longer in use).

The fact that your test case got this wrong is a good indicator that the ergonomics of your interface are not as good as they could be.  You should probably consider a design in which the ownership of the strings inserted is transferred to the hash table, so that `hash_table_remove()` is itself responsible for freeing the string.

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response. Regarding that last advice on your answer, I thought it was good practise to have the data structure not handle freeing memory of objects inserted into it. You learn as you go, I guess. Thank you so much!

Comment: @SaucyGoat: Often you'd separate the key and the object itself, with the key being managed by the data structure but the object managed by the calling code - it's just that in your case you've combined the two together (and your test code doesn't store anything except the key itself).